# Bulk API 2.0 sf_Error CaseTriggerMaster: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:

Tags: api, error, bulk-api, cpulimit, bulk

I am trying to run an update operation on Case object using Bulk API 2.0. I am using Python with requests package to send the API calls. I am able to get through the whole process of creating a job, uploading data, checking for job completion and getting the results. My csv size is 22kb and includes a little over 200 records with 5-6 fields each, so it should be well within the limits provided in the documentation.

It is able to process all the records when the number of records is low (like low double digit numbers).

Failed records csv output shows the sf_Error as "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:CaseTriggerMaster: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:--" for all failed records.

Since bulk API 2.0 does not involve any batch splitting on my end, there is no loops or "complex" code I write to upload the csv (which apparently could cause issues - [solution for apex cpu time limit exceeded exception](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96410/solution-for-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded-exception)). I am not sending any apex code to server end either in the process.

I tried to do the same thing in workbench the exact same way as provided in the documentation examples. While it works when fewer number of records are present, it runs into the same problem when the number of records are more. So, I do not think it's something to do with my python script.
I also don't think there is anything amiss with respect to data I am trying to upload as some of the records with exact fields get updated with no problem.
I also think bulk api 2.0 is specifically made for working with large number of records and I don't think it should have trouble processing a few hundred records.

Please help me in understanding what could be going wrong here and how I can fix it so that all records can be updated. I am running Python 3 with Pycharm IDE on my org's salesforce sandbox.

Thanks

Comment: There could be time-consuming operations in your triggers/other automations, since it works on smaller chunks

Comment: Is there any way I can change these triggers / automations?